# How to run a multithreaded program without a print statement?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question about how to run a multithreaded program without using a print statement. I kind of get the concept of multithreading but not that much. I have tried to create one by following a tutorial (but it has a printing statement).

I'm trying to find out how to do it, so I can proceed with a task was given to me. An explanation would be helpful or just an example of code.

Thank you.

Comment: please attach a link to the tutorial or provide a sample code, because without it the meaning your question is unclear

Comment: Run the program without the print statement? This is unclear.

Comment: here is the link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm and the first example is the one I have tried to implement. (Couldn't post it here)

Comment: What I mean is that I don't want to see anything in the output, I want it to be saved in the Database. I'm sorry for the unclear question.

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading and printing are two entirely unrelated things and the tutorial you followed most likely used the print statements to demonstrate the order of execution of the threads. You can always multithread without using print statements.

Comment: But then how I can know its working, even without any errors?

Comment: @RainyClouds, The way to know whether your code is working is by testing it. How to write tests in general is a book-level topic. (e.g., https://www.amazon.com/Growing-Object-Oriented-Software-Guided-Tests/dp/0321503627/) Short answer though is, you write a script that sets up a test database in a well-defined state, and then it runs the code in question, and then it looks in the database to see whether or not the code changed the database in the expected way.

Comment: Thank you Solomon for the help

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the tutorial was used to simply show the execution. The printing had nothing to do with the actual multithreading itself. Printing to the screen or console is not a requirement of creating a multithreaded environment. You could create a program which completes some actions and if those actions fail then it throws an exception which prints and error to the screen or logs the error to a file (something of this sort) and halts the program so that you know of any of this happens something went wrong otherwise everything went ok. It sounds like you should look into try and catch statements and exceptions. You may even look into using a logging framework or how to log exceptions yourself if you want to keep it simple and don't want to print errors to the console.

Decent try-catch read:
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/

Exceptions article:
https://www.protechtraining.com/content/java_fundamentals_tutorial-exceptions